# Filling a 26x36 grid with trominoes

Tags: mathematics, geometry, tiling, polyomino

Let's have 312 L-trominoes of three different colors, 104 trominoes of each color. Can you fill a 26x36 grid with these trominoes without two of the same colors touching side-to-side anywhere? In addition, the trominoes should not form any 2x3 rectangles.

Comment: Are the trominoes all L-trominoes? Does "touching" also include meeting at a corner?

Comment: All trominoes are L-shaped. Meeting at a corner is allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution:

> [image]

It appears there are many others.

Comment: Οut of thousands  of  MAPS your computer choose the most simple. Computers lack imagination.

Comment: I solved this by hand, tiling a 26x36 grid with 4x6 rectangles. "Be creative" wasn't a requirement in the problem description, so simplicity it is.